# How to use farmhash algorithm in place of default

Tags: rust

Im trying to have a go at using [farmhash (1.1.2)](https://crates.io/crates/farmhash) as a replacement for rusts default hashmap hashing algorithm (Siphash?) to see if I can get any speed improvements. I have had a go with using [twox-hash](https://crates.io/crates/twox-hash) and this gave a nice speed increase, although I would also like to test alongside farmhash, just for a comparison. The farmhash documentation only provides a short example similar to this:

```
let value: &str = "somestringkeyorsomthing";
let res64 = farmhash::hash64(&value.as_bytes());
println!("{:?}", res64)
>>> 12095987461079705245
```

How can I use this method to generate keys in a hashmap? If this is a complicated process, could anyone point me to a good example to follow?

Comment: [See benchmarks](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/hash-rs/). At this time, farmhash needs further adaptation to fit rust's streaming hashing API efficiently. This survey is very small, but there are two extreme ends. Short keys, FNV hash wins, long keys, xxhash dominates.

Comment: @bluss: One of the most impressive point of those benchmarks, as far as I am concerned, is the performance of `BTreeMap`; coming from C++ where `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` performance is crippled by the memory stability requirement, this is a welcome change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

```
#![feature(hashmap_hasher)]
extern crate farmhash;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::hash_state::DefaultState;

use farmhash::FarmHasher;

fn main() {
    let hm: HashMap<u32, u32, DefaultState<FarmHasher>> = 
        HashMap::with_hash_state(DefaultState::default());
}
```

You need to create the map with non-default hash state using `FarmHasher` from the library. `FarmHasher` implements `Hasher` and `Default` traits, and so it can be used with `DefaultState`.

Note that hasher configuration functionality is unstable, so you can only do this on nightlies with the corresponding feature enabled.